# Are mods capable of moving comments across posts?

Tags: support, comments

Apologies if this question has been already answered somewhere beyond my knowledge, but I've seen some newbie PMSE users commenting on the wrong topic because they still don't have enough reputation.

I also know that this question is quite irrelevant, I'm just asking it because I may be an organization-maniac or something like this...

So, **is there any defined process for these cases or should I forget about?** Not sure the outcomes of having these comments flagged...

As example, jasonk added a comment on his own answer as he hadn't enough rep to comment on someone else's answer. [How to measure a team member's performance?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/measuring-team-members-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, we don't have the ability to move comments, only to convert answers to comments.

What we can do is leave a comment to the user suggesting he move the comment himself, once he has enough rep. Or I can contact a developer and possibly have it moved, or we can simply delete it.

I'm not sure this justifies developer intervention since the user doesn't technically have the permissions to comment everywhere; thus, my inclination is to leave it as-is or delete it. I'm leaning towards leaving it, since the comment does appear to have some value.

If you see something out of place, I encourage you to flag it for moderator attention so one of us can take a look.

Comment: Agree that's waste of effort having devs working on a functionality like this for mods... even asking a dev to do it manually is a waste of time. So, as a rule of thumb, let's reply user's comment asking him to move the comment by himself.

Comment: @TiagoCardoso - Good idea!